# Webpack not updating page when I refresh to reflect new code

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack

So I am doing a project using Django and React.
I was working on it yesterday and it worked fine, but today after I run the command 'py ./manage.py runserver' along with 'npm run dev', my project loads but whenever I make changes to my code, these changes are not reflected when I update the page.
I tried fixing this but couldn't do it so far.

Here are my files:

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('development')
        // This has effect on the react lib size
    }),
  ],
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.34.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please consider to try this:

- Create a `.env` file inside your Application root
- Set `FAST_REFRESH=false` inside your `.env`
- Restart your Server